# Query from parent to child SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database where there is an inheritance from a parent class to multiple child classes. [image: UML of example database]

I have implemented the inheritance with [class table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html). Implementing it with one joint table would result in a really big table with a lot of null values that's why the class table inheritance was chosen. In the inheritance every parent-object may only be one of the child-objects, in the example this would mean every person can only be either a student, parent or teacher.

My problem now is how I could write a query getting all information about a person without knowing which type of person it is, only knowing the ssn. I know I can do this by left joining all child-tables and the parent-table but is there a way to do it so I don't have to do all the left joins? In reality there are A LOT more child-tables.

Everything about the database is written using SQLITE.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no..

You could use a query to write some SQL for you though:

```
SELECT 
    'LEFT JOIN ' || m.name || ' ON ' || m.name || '.ssn = person.ssn'
FROM 
  sqlite_master AS m
JOIN 
  pragma_table_info(m.name) AS p
WHERE 
  p.name = 'ssn'
```

If there are 100 tables with an ssn column it will write 100 joins for you